# Conditional shifting (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, if-statement

I have a data frame materialized by the following image:

[image: Input]

i would like to shift up by 1 cell the value in column "Weight[kg]" when the corresponding cell in column "Material" is not empty.

for example, in "Material" as there is Steel(16MnCr35), the weight "0.466" should shift up by 1 cell.

i though about numpy or if condition but nothing worked
the code tried is

`fp['Weight[kg]'] = np.where(fp['Material'].isnull(), fp['Weight[kg]'], fp['Weight[kg]'].shift(-1))`

Comment: You just want to shift the `fp['Weight[kg]']` series? Are you also going to shift the `fp['Material']` series up as well? If you shift the former without the latter, they will no longer line up and correspond.

Comment: Yes i will shift it as well, for the fp['Material'] i have to shift everything without condition so it is okay. but before i need to shift the fp['Weight[kg]']